# PHP json_encode - is there any input which makes this throw an error?

Tags: php, json

Whatever exotic `$var` I try to give to `json_encode($var)`, it never fails. It even deserialises some Objects somehow.

I'm looking for a test case where PHP finds something not json serializable (if it exists). Anyone know of any input where.

`$var`

by itself wouldn't be an error, but

```
json_encode($var)
```

fails? (throws Exception, triggers a warning, etc.)?

Comment: From docs: "Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure." So, it will return false, not exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a lot of data types that causes `json_encode` to actually fail, but you can verify the failure by checking if the result is (boolean) false (with strict comparison) or by having `json_encode` throw an exception (available since PHP 7.3.0).

Resources will fail, since they cannot be type casted to anything meaningful.

```
<?php
//Valid
var_dump(json_encode('Just a string'));

//Valid
var_dump(json_encode(['an array']));

//Valid 
var_dump(json_encode(null));

//Valid
var_dump(json_encode((new stdClass)));

//Invalid - returns false from json_encode
var_dump(json_encode(curl_init()));

//Invalid - Throws an JsonException since PHP 7.3.0
var_dump(json_encode(curl_init(), JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
```

Comment: curl_init() was exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Since php 8.0 last example return `'{}'` and don't throw exception